# Twitter url permalinks broken of wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, perl, url, twitter

This script was working perfectly for costum twitter URL shortener  but for some reason it just started to put broken links. 
And now all links are broken even those from before which were good.
It is showing on twitter domain.com/p(somenumber) and it is opening in browser that URL instead to redirecting to post. I guess the problem is in this Perl code which is autoposting wordpress posts on twitter.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

use Net::Twitter;
use Scalar::Util 'blessed';
use WWW::Facebook::API;
use JSON::Any;

use lib '/var/www/perl/.';

use MyLib::DB;
use MyLib::Settings;

my $settings = new Settings();
my $config = $settings->getConfig();

my $db = new DB(
                    dsn         =>$config->{sql_connection}->{dsn},
                    database    =>$config->{sql_connection}->{database},
                    server      =>$config->{sql_connection}->{server},
                    login       =>$config->{sql_connection}->{login},
                    password    =>$config->{sql_connection}->{password}
);

my %posts = $db->getList('select * from add_ready_post where wp_id > ( select max(wp_id) from add_ready_post where is_sent=1 ) and post_title <> "" limit 1;');

my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(legacy => 0);
my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
    traits   => [qw/OAuth API::REST/],
    consumer_key        => '',
    consumer_secret     => '',
    access_token        => '',
    access_token_secret => '',
);

map {
    my $message = $posts{$_}[4];
    my $id = $posts{$_}[0];
    my $url = ' domain.com/p' . $posts{$_}[1];
    if ( $message ne '' )
    {
#       print 'Original: ' . $message . "\n";
        if ( length( $message ) < 110 )
        {
            $message = $message . ".";
        }
        if ( length( $message ) > 110 )
        {
            $message = substr( $message, 0, 110 );
            $message =~ /.*(\s\w+)$/i;
            my $newMessage = substr( $message, 0, index( $message, $1 ) );
            $message = $newMessage . '...';
        }

#       print 'Result  : ' . $message . $url . "\n";

        my $result = $nt->update( $message . $url );
#       print Dumper( $result );

#       print "\n";

        my $sql = "UPDATE add_ready_post SET is_sent=1 WHERE id=" . int( $id ) . ";";
        $db->execute( $sql );

    }
} keys %posts;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably get closed with "not a real question" - but anyway - few comments:

Haven't idea what "doing" your `MyLib::DB;`, so can't analyze the code without knowing what contains the `%posts` hash.

Use `use warnings;` - for example you will get `$nt redefined` message...

```
 my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(legacy => 0);
 my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
```

Using `map {` in this way is not a best practice. It will be much readable using

```
foreach my $post (keys %posts) {
}
```

What you'll get when the message will not match here? And what if the index returns -1?

```
$message =~ /.*(\s\w+)$/i;
my $newMessage = substr( $message, 0, index( $message, $1 ) );
```

And when the message will contains only spaces? Think about:

```
if ( $message ne '' )
```

And here is much more... I'm understand than you learning perl but try decompose the problem to manageable parts and ask an real question.